# UIScrollView and Autoration issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I'm trying to understand an issue I'm having with an iOS Universal app. I have a UIScrollView which I want the page of to take up the full dimension of the device and adjust itself when rotating.

In my **viewDidLoad** method, I'm testing with:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor cyanColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = _scrollView.bounds.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = _scrollView.bounds.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [_scrollView addSubview:subview];

    }

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.bounds.size.width * colors.count, _scrollView.bounds.size.height);
```

then I added in the **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** method:

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.bounds.size.width * colors.count, _scrollView.bounds.size.height);

for (int i= 0; i< colors.count; i++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = _scrollView.bounds.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = _scrollView.bounds.size;


    UIView *subview= [[_scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:i];

    subview.frame= frame;
}
```

This seems to work, but I seem to have some clipping on the main view while the device is rotating.

**Here's a screenshot of what happens when rotating:**
[image]

I thought this happened because I changed the size after it was rotated, but I tried to handle it in the **willRotateToInterfaceOrientation** method, but it gave the wrong result...

- Am I handling this incorrectly?
- What would be the correct approach?

TIA!
S.

Am I handling this incorrectly?

Comment: Is the final layout after the rotation correct or not? ie. is your issue with the transition, or positioning the views correctly?

Comment: The final layout is correct, the issue seems to be in the transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the code that changes the bounds in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, but do so in an animation block (using `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:...]`)_so that the transition will be smooth rather than immediate.

An extra note is that inside willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, the parent view will not yet have been resized, so you cannot depend on it's bounds to calculate the final position of the views, rather you must do so manually.

Comment: About your extra note, how would you calculate the bounds manually to support standard resolutions and retina? Through an iVar set prior? Would that not also be the incorrect size?